# react-native: conditional rendering not working

Tags: react-native

In my app i display a loader when data is loading. When data returns i display it in a list. Here is a piece of the logic:

```
let content = null;
if(resultItems.length > 0 ){
  content = (
    <ScrollView style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#ddd', marginTop: 5, marginBottom: 0}}>
      {resultItems}
    </ScrollView>
  );
} else {
  content = (
    <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor : 'red', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
      <ActivityIndicator color="#368ec7" size={60} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

**content** is rendered in a View in my app. **resultItems** contains the returned data.

At first the loader is showing. However, when the data loads, the list gets rendered but the loader does not disappear.

**UPDATE** content is being rendered like so:

```
...
<View>
  {content}
</View>
...
```

**UPDATE** from what i have seen, the issue seems to stem from the fact that i am using conditional rendering with a ui element that gets its contents from somewhere. E.i.  something like this causes an issue:

{true && ({someJsxFromVariable})}

Comment: are you returning content, considering the above content is not in render()

Comment: Can you post complete code?

Comment: Yeah but its a lot. Can u check it here: https://justpaste.it/edit/15520951/840ff036

Comment: Did you resolve this? If so, can you please elaborate on the solution.

Comment: Are you having a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
render() {
 return(
  <View>
  {
   resultItems.length > 0
   ? <ScrollView style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#ddd', marginTop: 5, marginBottom: 0}}>
      {resultItems}
     </ScrollView>
   : <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor : 'red', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
      <ActivityIndicator color="#368ec7" size={60} />
     </View>
  }
  </View>
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that though you are conditional rendering, the property `animating` of `ActivityIndicator` is still `true`, which causes the spinner to be visible.

I would suggest using [react-native-loading-spinner-overlay](https://github.com/joinspontaneous/react-native-loading-spinner-overlay) library. It is a wrapper around the `ActivityIndicator` but easier to use. It uses a modal to display the `ActivityIndicator` and sets is state accordingly.

Usage

```
import Spinner from 'react-native-loading-spinner-overlay';

render() {
    <ScrollView style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#ddd', marginTop: 5, marginBottom: 0}}>
      <Spinner visible={resultItems.length > 0 ? false : true } />
      {resultItems}
    </ScrollView>
}
```